# HTTP Status Code 406

Tags: http, http-status-code-406

I am building a web server, I was wondering what status code should I use if the client wants to request this?

```
PUT /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1111
```

Lets say the client is trying to add a new file to the server, but that file already exist, what HTTP status code should the server respond with?

I read the definition for 406, on the e HTTP/1.1 RFC, but looks like it for something else.

Comment: How do you know that the client doesn't intend to *update* the resource?

Comment: Because the server am doing will only accept the creation of things and not the update of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like this is the case for a 405 response "Method not allowed", because this 
method is not allowed for the requested url.

"*for example, ... or using PUT on a read-only resource*"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Of course, that assumes you want to use the convention of using put only to insert new 
content and never to edit it.

Comment: Yeah its makes more sense than 406, for what I am doing. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

The exception contains this statusCode=Optional.of(406) , access rights to the particular service is not present for the user.

Enable the access to the user, then you will get the response from the rest calls.